# How to set fonts into action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to set fonts into my action bar but actually the setTitle the textview cant be found. So, Is there any idea how to do it?

Comment: please see the comment on the answer that I provide

Answer (score 0):

firstly : set the title to false, because we are using custom view

```
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

secondly : create titleview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Lastly :

```
//font file must be in the phone db so you have to create download file code
//check the code on the bottom part of the download file code.

   TypeFace font = Typeface.createFromFile("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/"   
    + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/files/" + "font name" + ".ttf");

    if(font != null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);
        TextView titleTv = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title));
        titleTv.setText(title);
        titleTv.setTypeface(font);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
    } else {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("  " + title); // Need to add a title
    }
```

DOWNLOAD FONT FILE : because i am storing the file into cloudinary so I have link on it to download it.

```
/**downloadFile*/
public void downloadFile(){
    String DownloadUrl = //url here
    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/files/");
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    if(list == null || list.length <= 0) {
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try{
                    showContentFragment(false);
                } catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadUrl));
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, null, ModelManager.getInstance().getCurrentApp().getRegular_font_name() + ".ttf");
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    } else {
        for (File files : list) {
            if (!files.getName().equals("font_name" + ".ttf")) {
                BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        try{
                            showContentFragment(false);
                        } catch (Exception e){
                        }
                    }
                };

                registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadUrl));
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, null, "font_name" + ".ttf");
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            } else {
                showContentFragment(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a part of your post?

Comment: what do you meant?

Comment: You added a post then an answer immediately afterwards. I was wondering if you might have accidentally posted some additional details of your post as an answer.

Comment: because there is choice from stackoverflow that you can post your question and answer in one time. I just want to share this for people that have problem to set the font to actionbar

Comment: I see. It's great that you want to help. :) But I think there's already a question like this here. You could've just added your answer there. :)

Comment: yes but I am using download file and also in that answer there is no direction to set font and download font file from link. and check if the font is null as well.

Comment: I see. Then I think it would help if you did post your answer on that post too. :)

Comment: i cant post because my point is not enough to add comment on other people post thats why i create this new post

Comment: Try to post it as an answer. Like "In addition to what xxxx answered~" something like that. :D

Comment: i see. So what you recommend me to do then?

Comment: Simply try to post your answer there. Your answer is detailed enough. Hopefully it would help other user's someday. :D Cheers!~

Comment: sure!! I hope that post can help me to gain more points as well and help other people. thanks. So do i need to delete this post?

Comment: Great you want to help :D Let's continue supporting the community!~ It's up to you. I guess. It might get down-voted by some strict users.